# Search form/function no results, Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have this search form which is search.blade.php for my building.blade.php the problem is it doesn't give me the the office that I searched in the search field

This is what it looks like when I tried to use {{dd($offices)}}; when I click search button in my search.blade.php  and then I removed it and it shows nothing, how do I make it work?

[[image: [1]]

search.blade.php

```
  @extends('layouts.main')
  @section('title', $search)
  @section('content')
 <div class="search">

          {!! Form::open(['method'=> 'GET','url'=>'offices','role'=>'search']) !!}
        <div class="input-group col-xs-4 col-md-6" >
          <input type="text" name="search" class="form-control" placeholder="Search...">
         <span class="input-group-btn">
           <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info btn-md">Search
           </button>
          </span>
            </div>
             {!! Form::close()!!}

           </div>
              <hr>
        <table class="table">

          <thead>
              <th>Office Name</th>
              <th>Belongs to</th>
              <th>Office Floor</th>
          </thead>

          <tbody>
            @foreach($offices as $office)
              <tr>
                <td>{{($office)->name}}</td>
                <td>{{$office->building->name}}</td>
                <td>{{$office->floor}}</td>

                <td class="a">

                    @if(!Auth::guest())

                   <a href="{{route('editofficeform', ['id'=>$building->id, 'office_id'=>$office->id])}}" class="btn btn-success btn-sm">Edit</a>
                  <a href="{{route('deleteoffice', $office->id)}}" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">Delete</a>
                  @endif
                </td>
              </tr>
            @endforeach
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
      </div>
    </div>
        @endsection
```

Building.blade.php

```
  @extends('layouts.main')
  @section('title',$building->name)
  @section('css')
  @stop
  @section('content')
 <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-12">
              <img src="{{URL::to('/assets')}}/{{$building->picture}}" alt="" style="height:300px; width:500px;">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
              {{$building->name}}
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

        <div class="rows">

        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">

          <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-6">

  @if(!Auth::guest())
                <a href="{{route('createofficeform', $building->id)}}" class="btn btn-primary btn-md">Create an Office</a>
  @endif
        </div>

          {!! Form::open(['method'=> 'GET','url'=>'offices','role'=>'search']) !!}
        <div class="input-group col-xs-4 col-md-6" >
          <input type="text" name="search" class="form-control" placeholder="Search...">
         <span class="input-group-btn">
           <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info btn-md">Search</i>
           </button>
          </span>
            </div>
             {!! Form::close()!!}


        <table class="table">
          <div class="ttitle">
          <thead>
              <th>Office Name</th>
              <th>Office Floor</th>
          </thead>


          <tbody>
            @foreach($offices as $office)
              <tr>

                <td>{{optional($office)->name}}</td>
                <td>{{$office->floor}}</td>
                <td class="a">

                  @if(!Auth::guest())

                  <a href="{{route('editofficeform', ['id'=>$building->id, 'office_id'=>$office->id])}}" class="btn btn-success btn-sm">Edit</a>
                  <a href="{{route('deleteoffice', $office->id)}}" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">Delete</a>
                  @endif
                </td>
              </tr>
            @endforeach
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
      </div>
        @endsection
```

OfficeController.php

```
 public function index()
        {
            $search = \Request::get('search');
    $offices = Office::where('name','like','%'.$search.'%')->get();
return view('search',compact('offices','search'));
      }
```

Office.php

```
     namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Office extends Model
{
    public function building(){
      return $this->belongsTo('App\Building');
    }
}
```

Building.php

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Building extends Model
{
    public $table = 'buildings';

    public function offices(){
      return $this->hasMany('App\Office');
    }
}
```

Routes

```
Auth::routes();


Route::get('/', 'BuildingController@index')->name('index');

Route::get('building/{id}', 'PageController@show')->name('building');

Route::get('office/{id}', 'OfficeController@show')->name('officeMenu');

Route::get('offices', 'OfficeController@index');


Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth']], function () {

  Route::get('buildings/create', 'BuildingController@create')->name('createbform');

  Route::post('building/create/store', 'BuildingController@saveBuilding')->name('createbuilding');

  Route::get('building/{id}/edit', 'BuildingController@edit');

  Route::post('building/{id}/edit', 'BuildingController@update')->name('editbuilding');

  Route::get('building/{id}/delete', 'BuildingController@destroy');

  Route::get('building/{id}/offices/create', 'OfficeController@create')->name('createofficeform');

  Route::post('building/{id}/offices/create/store', 'OfficeController@store')->name('createoffice');

Route::get('building/{id}/offices/{office_id}/edit', 'OfficeController@edit')->name('editofficeform');

Route::post('building/{id}/offices/{office_id}/edit', 'OfficeController@update')->name('editoffice');


  Route::get('offices/{id}/delete', 'OfficeController@destroy')->name('deleteoffice');
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use *ILIKE* instead of *LIKE* for this, because, the name of the Office is **Case Room** and you're looking for an office name that has the words **"case"**. Given that *LIKE* in SQL is case sensitive, it will not find what are you looking for.

Comment: $search = \Request::get('search');
    $offices = Office::where('name','ilike','%'.$search.'%')->get();
return view('search',compact('offices','search'));   @oscar.rpr   is this right?

Comment: Undefined variable: building (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\Eguide\resources\views\search.blade.php) it shows this  @oscar.rpr

Comment: That's another issue, you're not passing the building variable to the search.blade file, make sure that you pass it to the view

Comment: How do I pass it ? @oscar.rpr

Comment: You can put in your blade file instead of $building to $office->building->id

Comment: <a href="{{route('editofficeform', ['id'=>$building->id, 'office_id'=>$office->id])}}" class="btn btn-success btn-sm">Edit</a>   I think the issue is here.. I have two blades that have this code is that ok? @oscar.rpr

Comment: cause that seems fine the edit works and everything its just the search is not working or something @oscar.rpr

Comment: got it @oscar.rpr

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using this one `<a href="{{route('editofficeform', ['id'=>$building->id, 'office_id'=>$office->id])}}" class="btn btn-success btn-sm">Edit</a>`    I used this as what @oscar.rpr said

`<a href="{{route('editofficeform', ['id'=>$office->building->id, 'office_id'=>$office->id])}}" class="btn btn-success btn-sm">Edit</a>`